# Django Suit not showing date & time widgets

Tags: django, django-suit

Im using Django 1.10 and Django-Suit 0.2.20 . Usually the `DateFields` `DateTimeFields` etc in the django admin show a widget with a calendar. After intalling Django-Suit I cant see that widget anymore. Is there any way put them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the solution how to make native django widgets working but there is a workaround to use suit widgets as defaults instead (taken from [discussion on github](https://github.com/darklow/django-suit/issues/481)):

```
from django.db import models as django_models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.options import FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS
import suit.widgets

FORMFIELD_FOR_DBFIELD_DEFAULTS.update({
    django_models.DateTimeField: {
        'form_class': forms.SplitDateTimeField,
        'widget': suit.widgets.SuitSplitDateTimeWidget
    },
    django_models.DateField: {'widget': suit.widgets.SuitDateWidget},
    django_models.TimeField: {'widget': suit.widgets.SuitTimeWidget},
})
```